# Unexpected and inconsistent behavior `c`oncatenating doubles/integers with Date

Tags: r, date, vector, concatenation

`c`oncatenating *double* (*integer*) with a *Date* doesn't appear to be commutative:

```
c(.1, Sys.Date())
# [1]     0.1 18649
c(as.integer(.1), Sys.Date())
# [1]     0 18649
```

whereas

```
c(Sys.Date(), .1)
# Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied
c(Sys.Date(), as.integer(.1))
# Error in as.Date.numeric(e) : 'origin' must be supplied
```

The second case is **unexpected**, because `?c` rather documents on hierarchical behavior than on this kind of non-commutative arrangement-behavior:

> The output type is determined from the highest type of the components
> in the hierarchy NULL < raw < logical < integer < double < complex <
> character < list < expression. [...] factors are treated only via
> their internal integer codes.

I couldn't find a documentation on what happens with *Date* objects using `c`, but I would **expect** *Date* objects, similarly to *factors*, to be coerced to *integer*, as it's seemingly happening in the first case shown above—However, even the first case behaves differently, and we don't get *integers*!

```
str(c(as.integer(.1), Sys.Date()))
# num [1:2] 0 18649  ## numeric instead of integer!
```

Regardless, the non-commutative hierarchy of the two cases shown above is very unexpected.

All the other guys work as documented:

```
c(.1, as.expression(.1));c(as.expression(.1), .1)
c(.1, as.list(.1));c(as.list(.1), .1)
c(.1, as.character(.1));c(as.character(.1), .1)
c(.1, as.complex(.1));c(as.complex(.1), .1)
c(TRUE, as.integer(.1));c(as.integer(.1), TRUE)
c(as.raw(.1), as.logical(.1));c(as.logical(.1), as.raw(.1))
c(NULL, as.logical(.1));c(as.logical(.1), NULL)
c(NULL, as.raw(.1));c(as.raw(.1), NULL)
```

as well as:

```
str(c(.1, as.factor(.1)));str(c(as.factor(.1), .1))
str(c(as.integer(.1), as.factor(.1)));str(c(as.factor(.1), as.integer(.1)))
```

### Question

Is there any documentation that covers this behavior when `c`oncatenating *Dates* with *numbers*? What might be the intention for it? Should this perhaps be reported as a bug?

Comment: Note that `c()` is a generic function. It can have special methods depending on the class of the first parameter. There is in fact a `c.Date` function. Thus it tries to coerce numeric values to Dates but it can't do that without an origin. you can see the other specials methods of `c()` with `methods(c)`

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick I actually looked into `base:::c.Date` and `?Date`. Nonetheless, the behavior is inconsistent and nowhere documented. There's also no way to do sth like `c(Sys.Date(), .1, origin="1970-01-01")` and usage and returned values are unsatisfactory ambivalent, and I thus can't understand the design. However could you elaborate a little on _"special methods depending on the class of the first parameter"_?

Comment: "Special methods depending on the class of the first parameter" is basically [S3 dispatch](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html). You can write methods for generic functions that do whatever you like. They don't have to be consistent at all with the base usage. (Like think about how `ggplot2` uses `+`). The `c.Date` function calls `as.Date()` on the values you provide. Unfortunately numeric types in R do not automatically convert to Dates. But you could write your own class that can correctly respond to `as.Date()` and then can use that with `c.Date()`.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks for the reading! Of course we can change source code we don't like. My intention is to point out that the shown case doesn't seem to be covered by the design, and also doesn't throw a message on an error that can be solved. (BTW, The core of `c.Date` is `lapply(list(Sys.Date(), .1), function(e) unclass(as.Date(e)))` and produces the error. Interestingly, though, the order `list(.1, Sys.Date())`, `list(Sys.Date(), .1)` doesn't matter here.)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the point. Generic functions in general are not commutative in R. Dispatch only happens on the class of the first parameter. In this case a Date can be coerced to a numeric value without additional information, but a numeric value cannot be coerced to a Date without additional information. I'm not sure what you are proposing. Do you want to change the documentation of `c` so that it makes it clear there many be non-standard methods? It doesn't make sense to add `origin=` to `c.Date` because you can also pass non-numeric values and those might need different parameters

Comment: @MrFlick You're right, it doesn't make sense to add `origin` to `c.Date`, I've tried it with other values (factor) and it would throw an other error. And if I try it with something else, the error would be another one. Previous comment deleted.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks to your reference to dispatch I understand the non-commutativity of generic functions. However, the usage of `c.Date` is still inconsistent, especially also the message _"'origin' must be supplied"_ cannot be served by the user. One has to remember "don't concatenate dates with numbers" which is unsatisfying, even when the doc would note "don't do that because it doesn't work well". I wouldn't propose rather to add a `stopifnot` than to add `origin` to `c.Date`.

Comment: Sure. The error message could be better. But the `traceback()` is accurate. I guess one shortcoming of R is that it doesn't really have a way to check of implicit coercion between classes is possible. There's no real way to predict all the possible types of classes that someone might choose to pass to `c.Date()`, like, what if they tried to pass in a data.frame. In the case of `c(Sys.Date(), iris)` you do get "cannot covert to date" because `as.Date.data.frame` does not exist. I guess the "problem" is that `as.Date.numeric` exists but it requires additional information.

Comment: @MrFlick I wrote to r-devel, thanks for the discussion!

Comment: Also thanks @RuiBarradas !

Comment: You might find further information in one of the vctrs package vignettes which is partly motivated by this exact issue. https://vctrs.r-lib.org/#motivation